# C++, error: invalid use of qualified-name

Tags: c++

1.I did something as below:

```
template <class T>
class RBTree{
public：
    struct TreeNode{
       T data;
       bool color;
       TreeNode* left;
       TreeNode* right;
       TreeNode* parent;
       static TreeNode* NIL; 

       TreeNode(T data, TreeNode* parent, TreeNode* left = NIL, TreeNode* right = NIL)   
                        :data(data), color(RED), left(left), right(right), parent(parent){}
    }
    TreeNode* TreeNode::NIL = new TreeNode(-1, nullptr);
};
```

And it throws me an error...

```
[Error] invalid use of qualified-name 'RBTree<T, Comp>::TreeNode::NIL'
```

I really don't know why... after I made it outside of the whole class RBTree, as blow, it works...

```
template <class T>
class RBTree{
...
};

template <class T>
typename RBTree<T>::TreeNode* RBTree<T>::TreeNode::NIL = new TreeNode(-1, nullptr);
```

But I don't know why I got an error at the first time?

I think the grammar may be correct...

2.Soon I made my class as below.

```
//in RBTree.hpp
template <class T>
class RBTree{
public:
    ... //the same as above
private:
    TreeNode* root;
};
template <class T>
typename RBTree<T>::TreeNode* RBTree<T>::TreeNode::NIL = new TreeNode(-1, nullptr);

//in RBTree_IMPL.hpp
template <class T>
void RBTree<T>::insert(const T & data){
    if(root == nullptr){
        root = new TreeNode(data, nullptr);
        ... 
    }
    ...
}

//in RBTree_test.cpp
int main(){
    RBTree<int> rb;
    rb.insert(3);
}
```

I got lots of errors like

```
[Error] recursive evaluation of default argument for 'RBTree<T>::TreeNode::TreeNode(T, RBTree<T>::TreeNode*, RBTree<T>::TreeNode*, RBTree<T>::TreeNode*) [with T = int]'
```

maybe about the constructor of the inner class TreeNode. The error happens when I use the RBTree::insert() in main() to create the 'root' node.

I don't know why. It maybe very interesting to probe the static member. And thank you for reading my question. Due to the fact that in 90 mins can only ask one question, so I write two questions in it.. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

static data members must be defined at namespace scope.  You were attempting to define it at class scope.

As for the second error, you have an infinite recursion.  You are trying to define what the value of NIL is, but since you aren't providing all the arguments, the default arguments are being used, which means you are effectively declaring

```
template <class T>
typename RBTree<T>::TreeNode* RBTree<T>::TreeNode::NIL = 
    new TreeNode(-1, nullptr,NIL,NIL);
```

Maybe you intended for the default arguments to be nullptr instead.

Comment: umm, but what about the second question? I added the insert function to make it seem to be completed.

Comment: @wind2412: I'm not able to reproduce that error.  It seems like the error is concerning code you didn't post.

Comment: @wind2412: The error is talking about a TreeNode constructor which takes two arguments.

Comment: My fault. At first I want to make my code neat. But it seems there has a negative effect. Now I've put the useful code fully on the website.

Comment: Got it. Thank you !